# VB DataGridView click event to variables

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview, datagrid

[Where I want the code to go and what the window looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVcsT.png)

I am creating an application which helps you select the components you want in your computer build. It pulls the components name and price from a database I have created in Access.

I want the user to be able to double click on one of the items in the DataGrid (FullRowSelect) it will update [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHLyh.png) screen (interface isn't completed) with the name and price of the component once it has been selected.

What I need is for someone to tell me how I am meant to put the Name and Price of the selected component into the two variables. I've tried a few different ways but none of them worked correctly.

Thank you for any help :)

Comment: Rather than variables, consider a class to hold the Name, Price and perhaps component type

Comment: The problem isn't the variables, its getting the information out of the dataset after the user clicks one of the components.

Answer (score 0):

Found out a solution to my problem. A single line of code.

componentName = tableGPU.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Value